# Optional element in XPath

Tags: xpath

How to make `b` and `a` optional in the following expression?

```
//td[@class='ttr_interest']/b/a/text()
```

Basically `/b/a` may or may not present in tree (only `a` or only `b` or both or neither can be present). How in general to specify optional elements?

I want to capture text enclosed into `td` whether or not that text is additionally enclosed by `<a>` and `<b>`.

Sample as requested

```
<td>
<a href="#">text_to_capture</a>
</td>

<td>
<b><a href="#">text_to_capture</a></b>
</td>

<td>
text_to_capture
</td>
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample XML input document?

Comment: Updated. Let me know if still not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
  (//td[@class='ttr_interest']
|
  //td[@class='ttr_interest']/a
|
  //td[@class='ttr_interest']/b/a
  )
   /text()
```

This selects any text-node chile of any element selected by one of the three XPath expressions that are union-ed together in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say in which context you do this (XSLT?), but here is a Python/lxml suggestion:

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root>
 <td>
  <a href="#">text_to_capture</a>
  </td>

  <td>
   <b><a href="#">text_to_capture</a></b>
  </td>

  <td>
   text_to_capture
  </td>
</root>"""  

doc = etree.fromstring(XML)
expr = "//td//text()"

texts = doc.xpath(expr)
print texts    # includes whitespace-only nodes

for t in texts:
    if t.strip():
        print t.strip()
```

Output:

```
['\n  ', 'text_to_capture', '\n  ', '\n   ', 'text_to_capture', '\n  ', '\n   text_to_capture\n  ']
text_to_capture
text_to_capture
text_to_capture
```

This solution selects all text in `<td>` regardless of the names of any `<td>` child elements.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After comments changed xpath to fit question

```
<bar>
  xxxx
  <foo>xxx</foo>
  <barfoo>
    <foo>xxx</foo>
  </barfoo>
</bar>
```

Use this xpath

```
//bar//*/text()|//bar/text()
```

Comment: Not really. I want to capture text enclosed into `td` whether or not that text is additionally enclosed by `<a>` and `<b>`. I don't see how `descendant::` can help here. Thx

Comment: this only works if `a/b` exist. In case they don't exist expression will fail to find text